# Parbox on the table not vertically centered and remove space before enumeration but topsep=0pt failed

Tags: tables, enumitem, landscape

My problems:

1. I'm using parbox to give line break on the table but not vertically centered. If you zoom in on the head of the table, you'll see it's centered on the bottom, but i want it on the middle. (Goal: vertically centered).
2. line start of the enumeration is different with the line start of the text. Seems like there's a vertical space before the list, and i want to remove that. Using topsep=0pt give me nothing. (Goal: the same line start).

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{BOO}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \begin{landscape}
        \section{My Table}
        \begin{table}[h!]
            \centering
            \caption{This is a table}
            \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}| p{3cm} |p{3cm}|p{3.2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{3cm}|}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Whatever}} 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\parbox[H]{3cm}{\centering \textbf{Random \\ Text}}} 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Whatever}} 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Whatever}} 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\parbox[H]{2cm}{\centering \textbf{Random \\ Text}}} 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\parbox[H]{3cm}{\centering \textbf{Random \\ Text}}}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\parbox[H]{3cm}{\centering \textbf{Random \\ Text}}}\\
                \hline
                \lipsum[2][1]
                & \begin{enumerate}[left= 0pt, label=\arabic*), noitemsep, topsep= 0pt]
                    \item \lipsum[1][1]
                    \item \lipsum[1][1]
                \end{enumerate} 
                & \begin{enumerate}[left= 0pt, label=\arabic*), noitemsep, topsep= 0pt]
                    \item \lipsum[1][1]
                    \item \lipsum[1][1]
                \end{enumerate} 
                &\begin{enumerate}[left= 0pt, label=\arabic*), noitemsep, topsep= 0pt]
                    \item \lipsum[1][1]
                    \item \lipsum[1][1]
                \end{enumerate}
                &\begin{enumerate}[left= 0pt, label=\arabic*), noitemsep, topsep= 0pt]
                    \item \lipsum[1][1]
                \end{enumerate}
                &\lipsum[2][4]
                & \lipsum[2][1]\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
    
\end{document}
```

Help me please. Thanks!

Comment: Off-topic: the options `noitemsep, topsep=0pt` can be combined into `nosep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the first issue, I suggest you load the `makecell` package and use `\makecell{...}` directives instead of `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\parbox[H]{3cm}{\centering ...}}` wrappers.

To fix the second issue, I suggest you make use of some of the `enumitem` package's machinery -- specifically, its `\newlist` and `\setlist` directives -- to create a bespoke `enumerate`-like list environment (called `ColEnum` in the example code below) that encases the list's contents in a `minipage`. Doing so will strip off the vertical whitespace.

I would also like to suggest that you use `\RaggedRight` directives in the narrow columns, to switch from full justification to ragged-right.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,pdflscape}

% new:
\usepackage{makecell} % for '\makecell' macro
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage{enumitem} % for '\newlist' and '\setlist' macros
\newlist{ColEnum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[ColEnum,1]{label = \arabic*), left = 0pt, nosep, 
          before= {\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight},
          after = {\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{landscape}
\section{A section header, followed by a table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{This is a table\strut}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}   | p{3cm}   | p{3cm}   |
                 p{3.2cm} | p{2.5cm} | p{2.5cm} | p{3cm}|}
\hline
\bfseries\makecell{Whatever}  & 
\bfseries\makecell{Random \\ Text} & 
\bfseries\makecell{Whatever} & 
\bfseries\makecell{Whatever} & 
\bfseries\makecell{Random \\ Text} & 
\bfseries\makecell{Random \\ Text} & 
\bfseries\makecell{Random \\ Text} \\
\hline
\RaggedRight\lipsum[2][1] & 
\begin{ColEnum}
   \item \lipsum[1][1]
   \item \lipsum[1][1]
\end{ColEnum} & 
\begin{ColEnum}
   \item \lipsum[1][1]
   \item \lipsum[1][1]
\end{ColEnum} &
\begin{ColEnum}
   \item \lipsum[1][1]
   \item \lipsum[1][1]
\end{ColEnum} &
\begin{ColEnum}
   \item \lipsum[1][1]
\end{ColEnum} &
\RaggedRight\lipsum[2][4] & 
\RaggedRight\lipsum[2][1] \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
    
\end{document}
```